# Как выделить края

Tags: css

У меня есть такая картинка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли с помощью сss найти углы в ней, ну места где переходит с черного на серый и чтоб она эти места выделила или закрасила белым цветом? может фильтр есть?,

Comment: конечно можно => открыть векторный редактор => векторизировать растр => на выходе получаем вот это => https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyWPMKb

Comment: @MaximLensky а как векторный ваш редактор называеться?

Comment: я делал в inkscape